# Run Azure devops pipeline as a azure AD user user

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines

I would like to run frontend end to end test from an azure devops pipeline, the website requires login using azure ad.
Unfortunately it is not easy to automate the login (sometimes involves sending code via email).
I tried using oauth and jwt tokens, but for some reason my app authentication does not recognize it when deployed to azure website.
What is the best way to have access to login protected website from azure pipeline?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think using an orgnization wide AD account [is not secure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-authorization-scope), especially you're in a public cloud, that's why Azure provides a [life-time limited project scope account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken). If you really want to use AD account, save its credentials in Azure Key Vault, then during the pipeline time, [retrieve the credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) by the default project scope token, then you can do anything you want with the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience regarding this, but I've done something similair using a Service Principal or Managed Identity.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using oauth and jwt tokens, but for some reason my app authentication does not recognize

After a while I actually figured out that there was an identity provider configured, and there was kind of double authentication configured. After removing the jwt token started working perfectly.
In any case thanks a lot for your answers!